# How do I dig into Active Record association meta info?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a table with data I pull from an external source.  It has three different columns that are hierarchical in nature and reference other tables.  The foreign keys are NOT constrained however, so data in those fields is not necessarily valid.

I'm trying to write something generic that will print out any records with values that don't reference an existing row in the parent table for a given date.

I've basically got something like this:

```
klass.where(:date => date).each do |rec|
    next if rec.send(parent)
    # do stuff with rec
end
```

Where `klass` is the model for the table and `parent` is a symbol of a declared 'belongs_to' association.

This method works, however, there may be tens of thousands of records for the day, but unique values on the key are fewer than 100.  The repeated lookups into the parent table are unpleasantly time consuming.  What I'd like to do is stash all the keys I've already looked up and only perform the lookup on new keys.

Towards this end, I'd like to be able to retrieve the field name that has the foreign key reference at runtime.  Ideally this would work regardless of whether or not it's using the default naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your schema, but this needs to be attacked in your database table, not in code, especially if you're dealing with "tens of thousands" of records.

As a first try, I'd have a "last_checked" field which is a DateTime value. At the start of the program's run, I'd capture the maximum value for that field, + 1 second, as my `last_ran` value. Any record that is older than that time is a candidate for looking at. Each record you look at gets the `last_checked` field updated to the current `DateTime.now` value. You can whittle down the list of candidate records without beating up Ruby that way.

Comment: I opted to abuse Ruby instead :)  I ended up dancing around a bit with the reflect_on_all_associations method.  I'm running this against one day's worth of data after it has fully loaded, which I think ends up being fundamentally the same as what you've suggested.